# deleting words from a file and saving the rest to the same file

Tags: python, file

I have a trivial problem

I want the words that were removed to all be uploaded to the same file where I'm making a mistake: D

```
infile = "tada.txt"
outfile = "tada.txt"

word = "vul"
tada=(''.join(word))

delete_list = tada
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
```

from text

```
this is vul great
```

if there is a word vul in the file

output is

```
this is great
```

so I want the same output to be in the same file

but the problem is that the script deletes everything and the file remains empty

Comment: What's your question exactly? Do you know why the problem is happening? (Hint: [What does `w+` do?](/a/16208298/4518341)) What research have you done? What have you tried to fix it? Please read [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify. Then once that problem is fixed, it looks like there are two more problems (`for word in delete_list` and `is  great`). You might want to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [mre]. For reference, ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) on SO.

Comment: @wjandrea ok sory I've been trying to get this new one in python so it's beyond me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively change a file "in place" by using Python's [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module. Here's how it could be used to what you want (i.e. remove words from each line).

**Note** that unlike your code, the following will delete whole *words* not letters of one in each line.

```
import fileinput

filepath = "tada.txt"
banned = {"bfd", "vul", "wtf"}  # Disallowed words.

with fileinput.input(files=filepath, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        words = [word for word in line.split() if word.lower() not in banned]
        print(' '.join(words))
```

Comment: my code is wrong removes other words as well

and your doing the same could you please adjust it

Comment: My code does not remove other words.

Comment: `word = "te"  intpu  test te tst  ouput s  s` im search output    `test tst`

Comment: Your (and my) code removes ***letters*** not words in each line.

Comment: I want to delete words onli

Comment: sorry for the confusion I just want to delete the words

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: yes this im search thanx